# Swift 3.0 passing NSArray as Any

Tags: swift, nsarray

We have a framework in Objective-C that has an `init` that has `NSArray` as a parameter.

Using the framework from Swift 3 all is good, except trying to pass an `NSArray` as a parameter.

Error is:

> Cannot convert value of type 'NSArray' to expected argument type '[Any]!'

Tried all sorts of type casting with no luck.  Anyway to get this to pass?

Please no comments on using `NSArray` in Swift, etc.

Comment: I wrote "if let arr = array as? [Any] " and it is okay

Comment: Show the actual Objective-C API and the actual code you using to call into it, please.

Comment: Thanks for the negative votes for no reason.  All have missed the point here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code seems to be working in playgrounds and not showing any errors

```
func someFunc(nsarray: NSArray) {
    /// some implementation
}

let array = [Any]()

someFunc(nsarray: array as NSArray)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty much what we ended up with

Comment: let arrayOfPages : [Any] = [Page0, Page1, Page2, Page3];